# How to find second largest number in a list?

Tags: python, list, max

So I have to find the second largest number from list. I am doing it through simple loops.

My approach is to divide a list into two parts and then find the largest number into two parts and then compare two numbers. I will choose the smaller number from two of them.  I can not use ready functions or different approaches.

Basically, this is my code. But it does not run correctly

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python2.7

alist=[-45,0,3,10,90,5,-2,4,18,45,100,1,-266,706]
largest=alist[0]
h=len(alist)/2 
m=len(alist)-h

print(alist)

for i in alist:
    if alist[h]>largest:
      largest=alist[h]
      i=i+1
print(largest)
```

Comment: What if both are in the same part of the list?

Comment: Here is the answer for your problem! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/251781/how-to-find-the-kth-largest-element-in-an-unsorted-array-of-length-n-in-on

Comment: What if the largest and the second largest number are in the same side of your divide? `[-10, -5, 10, 20]` for example? Your method will not capture `-5` rather than the desired `10`. Consider using a list (or [deque](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque)) of length 2 to store the two highest encountered numbers.

Answer (score 11):

O(n^2) algorithm:

```
In [79]: alist=[-45,0,3,10,90,5,-2,4,18,45,100,1,-266,706]

In [80]: max(n for n in alist if n!=max(alist))
Out[80]: 100
```

O(n) algorithm:

```
In [81]: alist=[-45,0,3,10,90,5,-2,4,18,45,100,1,-266,706]

In [82]: M = max(alist)

In [83]: max(n for n in alist if n!=M)
Out[83]: 100
```

Comment: This won't work for lists where the max is included twice. e.g. [0, 1, 2, 2]

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to sort the input, and this solution runs in O(n). Since your question says you cannot use builtin functions, you can use this

```
alist=[-45,0,3,10,90,5,-2,4,18,45,100,1,-266,706]
largest, larger = alist[0], alist[0]

for num in alist:
    if num > largest:
        largest, larger = num, largest
    elif num > larger:
        larger = num
print larger
```

**Output**

```
100
```

Keep track of the largest number and the second largest number (`larger` variable stores that in the code). If the current number is greater than the `largest`, current number becomes the `largest`, `largest` becomes just `larger`.

`largest, larger = num, largest` is a shortcut for

```
temp = largest
largest = num
larger = temp
```

**Edit:** As per OP's request in the comments,

```
def findLarge(myList):
    largest, larger = myList[0], myList[0]
    for num in myList:
        if num > largest:
            largest, larger = num, largest
        elif num > larger:
            larger = num
    return largest, larger

alist=[-45,0,3,10,90,5,-2,4,18,45,100,1,-266,706]

firstLargest, firstLarger  = findLarge(alist[:len(alist)//2])
secondLargest, secondLarger = findLarge(alist[len(alist)//2:])

print sorted((firstLarger, firstLargest, secondLarger, secondLargest))[-2]
```

Comment: thank you. but as i mentioned before i need use approach by dividing list into parts etc.

Comment: @ManuLakaster But what if the `largest` and `larger` are in the first list?

Comment: basically largest max in one part. larger is a second largest in part lol I wanted just divide a list into two parts, find largest and larger in each part(overall 4 numbers from two parts) and then find the second largest from 4 numbers))))

Comment: @ManuLakaster But why would you want to do that?

Comment: I try to implement divide and conquer algorithm :)

Comment: You just divide the list into two **once at the beginning**, but inside you don't do further division. This is not divide-and-conquer approach. You should instead call `findLarge` on two halves of the array, for each call to `findLarge`, unless there are only a certain number of elements, say 2.

Comment: @thefourtheye for secondLargest, secondLarger it gives me the same two numbers....

Comment: @ManuLakaster It gives `10 90 100 706` for me.

Answer (score 4):

If you want an approach that consist in dividing the list, the nearest thing I can think in, is a MergeSort, it works dividing the list in 2, but it **sorts** a list. Then you can take the last 2 elements.

```
alist = [1, 7, 3, 2, 8, 5, 6, 4]

def find_2_largest(alist):
    sorted_list = mergesort(alist)
    return (sorted_list[-2], sorted_list[-1])    

def merge(left, right):
    result = []
    i, j = 0, 0
    while i < len(left) and j < len(right):
        if left[i] <= right[j]:
            result.append(left[i])
            i += 1
        else:
            result.append(right[j])
            j += 1
    result += left[i:]
    result += right[j:]
    return result

def mergesort(alist):
    if len(alist) < 2:
        return alist
    middle = len(alist) / 2
    left = mergesort(alist[:middle])
    right = mergesort(alist[middle:])
    return merge(left, right)

print find_2_largest(alist)
```

Comment: Downvoted because this is so much code. In practice python's sorting function runs faster that mergesort and if you really care about speed then you should do it in O(n) instead of O(n*log(n))

Comment: @Manu Lakaster This is a well-known sort algorithm, try searching on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort, there is an animation, so you will understand how this algorithm works. **Remember** it's just sorting the list. PeterMichealLacey-Bordeaux yes, I just posted this 'approach' because of the OP requirement to make it dividing the list.

Comment: +1 because OP asked about dividing the list and because 'so much code' is sometimes exactly the right amount of code.

Answer (score 2):

O(n) solution

```
alist=[-45,0,3,10,90,5,-2,4,18,45,100,1,-266,706]
m = alist[:2] #m will hold 2 values, fill it with the first two values of alist
for num in alist:
    m = sorted(m + [num],reverse=True)[:2] #appends num to m and sorts it, takes only top 2
m[1] #the second highest element.
```

EDIT: changed to work with negative numbers. Basic description as follows

First I set m to be the first two elements of alist. As I iterate through alist I will be adding one value to the end of m, then sorting the three elements and throwing away the smallest one. This ensures that at the end m will contain the top two largest elements.

Comment: Can you give more explanation? Then I can +1 this =D

Comment: @ManuLakaster That's because you don't have to do it at all. The built-in function `sorted` handles it.

Comment: @ManuLakaster By the way, your logic has a flaw, you can't ensure if both of `second` and `first` numbers are in the same part of the list.

Comment: You'll have a problem if all the numbers in alist are negative.

Comment: Fixed the complaints. I would really just recommend using sort on the original list unless speed is really needed. I just like providing the lowest possible worst case run time of stuff.

Comment: This algorithm can be extended to deal with any number `m`, to return the `m`-th maximum element. It will, however, have a running time of `O(n*m log m)` due to the sorting of a list with size `O(m)`. However, for larger m, this means simply iterating through the list and doing more inline comparisons will lead to a worst-case of `O(n * m)`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
alist=[10, 0,3,10,90,5,-2,4,18,45,707, 100,1,-266,706, 1]
largest = alist[0]
second_largest = alist[0]
for i in range(len(alist)):
    if alist[i] > second_largest:
        second_largest = alist[i]
    if alist[i] > largest:
        tmp = second_largest
        second_largest = largest
        largest = tmp      

print(largest, second_largest)
```

Comment: cool. But can you divide list into two parts, find max element of those two parts, and then compare two numbers?

Comment: An issue with that approach would appear when the 2 largest numbers are in the 'part'. Maybe you can get an idea from this **sort algorith** called Merge Sort. It works dividing the list into two parts, but it's to sort a list. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort (See Animation)

Answer (score 1):

Without giving away code, I will give you my approach to solving this problem.

> > 1.) Take your list, and sort it from least to greatest. There is a python function to handle this
> >
> > 2.) Split your list into two sections
> >
> > 3.) Compare the two sections, take the half with the largest numbers, repeat #2
> >
> > 4.) When either half contains only two numbers, take the first number from that list

The challenge is you will have to decide what to do if the list cannot be evenly split. Obviously, in the real world, you would sort the list and return the second from last value, but if you must do it by performing a binary split, this is how I would do it :)

Comment: I like the answer because it provides *hint* instead of giving blocks of code.

Comment: If you already sort the list, you can just take the second last element. =D

Comment: The OP said he cannot use a different approach. I even mentioned that in my question if you read it all the way @justhalf

Comment: @samrap: The requirement is to use "divide-and-conquer", not to use sort. Of course, you can sort using divide-and-conquer approach, like Merge Sort, but it's unnecessary here.

Comment: @justhalf I think nobody understands my question. I think i needed to explain more.....Got confused in different approaches here ;(

Comment: I've linked another question similar to what you're looking for, and I've given my answer here. Hope that answers your question

Answer (score 1):

Second largest **number** in the list:

```
alist=[-45,0,3,10,90,5,-2,4,18,45,100,1,-266,706]
second_highest_number = sorted(list(set(alist)))[-2]
```

If you only want the 2nd largest **element** in the list (in cases where the highest value may occur **twice**), just skip the set() and list() call.

```
alist=[-45,0,3,10,90,5,-2,4,18,45,100,1,-266,706]
second_highest_number = sorted(alist)[-2]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
biggest = None
second_biggest = None

biggest = num_list[0]
if num_list[1] > biggest:
   second_biggest = num_list[1]
else:
   second_biggest = biggest
   biggest = num_list [1]

for n in num_list [2:]:
    if n >= biggest:
        biggest, second_biggest = n, biggest
    elif n >= second_biggest:
        second_biggest = n

print second_biggest
```

Comment: Can yo explain please what are you doing here?

Comment: @ManuLakaster Read the code carefully, what lines are confusing you?

Answer (score 0):

I'm amazed that most answers (except by Christian) didn't try to answer OP's real question of finding the solution using **divide-and-conquer** approach.

This question is almost identical to this question: [Finding the second smallest number from the given list using divide-and-conquer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19415821/finding-the-second-smallest-number-from-the-given-list-using-divide-and-conquer/19424799#19424799), but it tries to find the least instead of the largest.

For which this is [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19415821/finding-the-second-smallest-number-from-the-given-list-using-divide-and-conquer/19424799#19424799):

```
def two_min(arr):
    n = len(arr)
    if n==2:
        if arr[0]<arr[1]:                   # Line 1
            return (arr[0], arr[1])
        else:
            return (arr[1], arr[0])
    (least_left, sec_least_left) = two_min(arr[0:n/2]) # Take the two minimum from the first half
    (least_right, sec_least_right) = two_min(arr[n/2:]) # Take the two minimum from the second half
    if least_left < least_right:            # Line 2
        least = least_left
        if least_right < sec_least_left:    # Line 3
            return (least, least_right)
        else:
            return (least, sec_least_left)
    else:
        least = least_right
        if least_left < sec_least_right:    # Line 4
            return (least, least_left)
        else:
            return (least, sec_least_right)
```

You can try to understand the code and change it to take the two largest. Basically you divide the array into two parts, then return the two largest numbers from the two parts. Then you compare the four numbers from the two parts, take the largest two, return.

This code has a bonus also for limiting the number of comparisons to `3n/2 - 2`.

Comment: 3n/2-2 means that we can have odd amount of numbers in a list right? :) @justhalf

Comment: It's integer division, so for `n=7` for example, the number of comparisons would be 3*7/2-2 = 8.

Comment: So does this answer your question?

Comment: yeah thank u:) helped me a lot. Just to make sure: what will happen with d and c algo if we have 2^k+1??? Just interesting)

Comment: What do you mean by 2^k+1?

Answer (score 0):

```
alist = [-45,0,3,10,90,5,-2,4,18,45,100,1,-266,706]
largest = 0
second_largest = 0
for large in alist:
  if second_largest < large:
    second_largest = large

  if largest < large:
    temp = second_largest
    second_largest = largest
    largest = temp

print "First Highest:- %s" %largest
print "Second Highest:- %s" %second_largest
```

Answer (score 0):

```
alist=[10, 0,3,10,90,5,-2,4,18,45,707, 100,1,-266,706, 1]
print(max(alist))
second_largest=alist[0]
for i in range(len(alist)):
    if (alist[i]>second_largest and alist[i]!=max(alist)):
        second_largest=alist[i]
print(second_largest)
```

Comment: Can you add any explanation to your solution? Answers with explanations are more helpful than those without.

Answer (score 0):

```
 list1=[1,10,2,3,5,7,1,-32,90,99,99]
 max=0
 secmax=0
 for i in list1:
    if i>max:
       max=i
 for i in list1:
    if i>secmax and max!=i:
      secmax=i
 print(secmax)
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit *why* and *how* this code snippet provides an answer to the question? Thank you.

Comment: First find largest number in the list and stored the value in to max, Next loop the same list  check the value are not equal to max and find largest number so you get second largest number

Answer (score 0):

```py
alist=[-45,0,3,10,90,5,-2,4,18,45,100,1,-266,706]
sorted_list = sorted(set(alist))
sorted_list.pop()
print(max(sorted_list))
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is my program, irrespective of complexity

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    alist=[-45,0,3,10,90,5,-2,4,18,45,100,1,-266,706]
    alist1 = [ ]
    [alist1.append(x) for x in alist if x not in alist1]
    alist1.sort()
    print alist1[-2]
```